# Spring Data Mongodb Using Object Type to Collection

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Newbie Alert !

I just installed mongodb 2 days back and started creating REST api's over spring.

So i have a collection, userinfo, where a sample document would look like

```
{"_id":"5c62588e5e1fbc37dc9746d3","name":{"first":"rajan","last":"rawat"},"age":32}
```

I created the field **name** as Object type in the collection.

Now creating the entity class for it in java

```
@Document(collection = "userinfo")
 public class UserInfo {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private Name name;
    private int age;
}
```

where the Class Name is

```
public class Name {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

On running the API, the response I get is

> {"id":"5c62588e5e1fbc37dc9746d3","name":{"firstName":null,"lastName":null},"age":32}

If I change the type in UserInfo class to string like,

```
@Document(collection = "userinfo")
public class UserInfo {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

The response changes to

> {"id":"5c62588e5e1fbc37dc9746d3","name":"{ \"first\" : \"rajan\",
>   \"last\" : \"rawat\" }","age":32}

which basically gives a string representation of the object from collection.

My Questions.

1. Is there something wrong with the way I designed the collection in mongoDB. I am assuming my use case is a reason why the Object type would have been introduced.
2. How do I map this collection in java i.e @Document. What am I missing ? Is there Something else I need to configure in the **Class Name**

Comment: set `@Document` to Name class and add `@DBRef` to the field in the UserInfo

Comment: check this: https://lankydanblog.com/2017/05/29/embedded-documents-with-spring-data-and-mongodb/

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, I had already tried that just in case. Just that it does not fit conceptually, also, it doesnot work.

Comment: @dkb I dont get it. I have all the setters and getters, I checked the link and added a toString method and a constructor to the class Name. But still doesnot work. This is exactly what I want to know, what am I missing in the Class Name. it has getters and setter along with toString() which Iam afraid, is not what i think as I still get the json string without toString(), just that with NULL values. I thought it might be the constructor, but its not.

Comment: okay, let me try, will update, if possible can you share your source code via github or bitbucket?

Comment: @dkb i just added a zip with source at https://github.com/rajanRawat/RnD/raw/master/springDataMongoDB.zip

Comment: your project works fine, http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/all output: `[{"id":"5c6564954c8cc4269a12619b","name":{"firstName":"rajan","lastName":"rawat"},"age":32},{"id":"5c6564954c8cc4269a12619c","name":{"firstName":"rajan","lastName":"rawat"},"age":3}]`

Comment: @dkb yep, I just checked, it was fine the first time. Just that the the collection had entries for name with "first" and "last" instead of firstname / last name. Sorry for the silly mistake and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In your document your attributes name are "first" and "last", so in your class **Name** you need to use the same names so that the object can be mapped by spring.

just try this:

```
public class Name {

    private String first;
    private String last;
}
```